# Visual Basic date parsing into PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

I have the following LOC which takes a date item and parses it based on a "due" date. I am having trouble locating similar functions in PHP, aside from `strtotime()` which I'm guessing should become `$date_start = strtotime('+????');`.

```
date_start.AddDays((Weekday(int_day, FirstDayOfWeek.Monday) - 1) + 7)
```

Most critically, I have no clue what `Weekday` or `FirstDayOfWeek.Monday` would look like in PHP. What would the equivalent be?

Comment: You can use `date("N", $timestamp)` to get the day of the week (1-7, 1 is Monday). I think that's all you need to do this calculation.